flink syncs mysql to starrocks
Here's the background:
StarRocks 3.1.2, Flink 1.16, flink-sql-connection-mysql-cdc-2.2.0.jar, flink-connector-starrocks-1.2.9_flink-1.16.jar
Mysql5.7.4 enabled binlog
sql is as follows:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cvm_price_factor_sink (
    Id BIGINT,
    Region STRING,
    SelfVersionNo BIGINT,
    NextVersionNo BIGINT,
    ChargeDetailType INT,
    Multi DECIMAL,
    Div DECIMAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id, Region) NOT ENFORCED
    ) WITH (
    'connector' = 'starrocks',
    'sink.max-retries' = '10',
    'sink.properties.strip_outer_array' = 'true',
    'sink.properties.format' = 'json',
    'sink.buffer-flush.interval-ms' = '5000',
    'sink.properties.transaction.enabled' = 'false',
    'jdbc-url' = 'jdbc:mysql://xxx:9030',
    'username' = 'root',
    'password' = 'xxx',
    'load-url' = 'xxx:8030',
    'database-name' = 'dev_int1_brp_oss',
    'table-name' = 'cvm_price_factor');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cvm_price_factor_src_dev (
    Id BIGINT,
    Region STRING,
    SelfVersionNo BIGINT,
    NextVersionNo BIGINT,
    ChargeDetailType INT,
    Multi DECIMAL,
    Div DECIMAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id, Region) NOT ENFORCED
    ) WITH (
    'connector' = 'mysql-cdc',
    'server-time-zone' = 'Asia/Shanghai',
    'hostname' = 'xxx',
    'port' = '3306',
    'username' = 'root',
    'password' = 'xxx',
    'database-name' = 'dev_int1_brp_oss',
    'table-name' = 'cvm_price_factor');

INSERT INTO cvm_price_factor_sink SELECT * FROM cvm_price_factor_src_dev;

The error is as follows:

Caused by: com.starrocks.data.load.stream.exception.StreamLoadFailException: Can't find 'Status' in the response of transaction begin request. Transaction load is supported since StarRocks 2.4, and please make sure your StarRocks version support transaction load first. db: dev_int1_brp_oss, table: cvm_price_factor, label: flink-8fc21496-e705-4b29-9fa0-710442e0f250, response:
at com.starrocks.data.load.stream.TransactionStreamLoader.doBegin(TransactionStreamLoader.java:144)
at com.starrocks.data.load.stream.TransactionStreamLoader.begin(TransactionStreamLoader.java:99)
at com.starrocks.data.load.stream.DefaultStreamLoader.send(DefaultStreamLoader.java:169)
at com.starrocks.data.load.stream.v2.TransactionTableRegion.streamLoad(TransactionTableRegion.java:331)
at com.starrocks.data.load.stream.v2.TransactionTableRegion.flush(TransactionTableRegion.java:228)
at com.starrocks.data.load.stream.v2.StreamLoadManagerV2.lambda$init$0(StreamLoadManagerV2.java:220)
... 1 more

I want to synchronize the data from the specified library table in mysql to the corresponding library table in starrocks

return code: 200
Content-Length: 0
